# Force updating an android app's latest version in the background without the users having to press any Button

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application and I have been asked to do a strange stuff. My client wants me to force update the latest version of the application without showing the user that there is an update available and without making him press any update button and going to the Google Play Store to download the app. This all must be done seamlessly without the user doing anything to update his app. Now I have seen questions of force updating the app but they all tell that we need to be redirected to Google Play Store and the user needs to do some interaction. While what I am looking for is a seamless way of updating an app without the user interaction. So as soon as a new version is available it just starts downloading it if there is no change in the permissions in the manifest file. Though I am OK with the fact that a notification for the download will appear in the Notification bar. How does one achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. You can download the .apk file in the background, but the user must confirm its installation.

Comment: Is your client by any chance located in russia? Does he specialize in "targeted electronic direct marketing"?

Comment: Hi Sir
Thanks for your response.But i have a question here.When we change the auto update settings in google play then it downloads the latest version without the user having to do anything.I want something very similar...the only thing is the app should be updated even if auto update is not set to true..so i am looking for some way to do it through code..Need ur advice if its feasible

Comment: @EugenRieck: No Sir my client is in India and its not related toTEDM. Do you have some solutions for the issue i posted.

Comment: It is possible, but only if the device is rooted, you can issue a terminal command to open an apk on the file system and install it silently

Comment: This is not possible. But this open source GitHub project ([MAHAndroidUpdater][1])is completely providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater


  [1]: https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 0):

This code checks for updates of the Activity once a day and in the background. If an update (higher version than current) is found, it opens a Dialog and asks the user to open the market.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        /* Get Last Update Time from Preferences */
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        lastUpdateTime =  prefs.getLong("lastUpdateTime", 0);

        /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
        if ((lastUpdateTime + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

            /* Save current timestamp for next Check*/
            lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();           
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
            editor.putLong("lastUpdateTime", lastUpdateTime);
            editor.commit();       

            /* Start Update */           
            checkUpdate.start();
        }
    }

    /* This Thread checks for Updates in the Background */
    private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL updateURL = new URL("http://my.company.com/update");               
                URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                     baf.append((byte)current);
                }

                /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                final String s = new String(baf.toByteArray());        

                /* Get current Version Number */
                int curVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.app.id", 0).versionCode;
                int newVersion = Integer.valueOf(s);

                /* Is a higher version than the current already out? */
                if (newVersion > curVersion) {
                    /* Post a Handler for the UI to pick up and open the Dialog */
                    mHandler.post(showUpdate);
                }               
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };

    /* This Runnable creates a Dialog and asks the user to open the Market */
    private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Test.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Update Available")
            .setMessage("An update for is available!\\n\\nOpen Android Market and see the details?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:your.app.id"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            /* User clicked Cancel */
                    }
            })
            .show();
           }
    };   
}
```